# Calling a phone number from TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am testing this little code snippet on a tablet. So i am not sure if it is not working because of that. Nothing happens when i click the number. No error message or log shown in LogCat. Please look at my implementation below.:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public void callPolice(View view){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.policeno);
        String val = tv.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+val));
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.v("Calling", "Calling..... "+val);
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="999"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/policeno"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
        android:onClick="callPolice"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
      <uses-permission android:name = "andriod.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put **android:clickable="true"** in textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/policeno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:onClick="callPolice"
    android:text="999"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="13pt"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call you should use

```
Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
```

If you are using fragments the xml onclick may not work. So try implementing onclick listner. Put the log before starting activity.